# Как проверить является ли последовательность целых чисел упорядоченной на Ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Я новичок в Ассемблере и у меня возник следующий  вопрос:
имеется последовательность целых чисел. Необходимо определить является ли эта последовательность упорядоченной. Как это реализовать? Сам смог написать только инициализацию массива

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, ".1251");
    int f1, f2; // границы интегрирования
    int numb; // количество элементов последовательности
    int f; // счетчик, пока не заполним наш массив
    int x; //элемент последовательности
    int *num, *num2; //массивы
    int i, z = 0, k = 0, a, b;
    cout << "Введите количество элемнетов последовательности: ";
    cin >> numb;
    num = new int[numb];
    num2 = new int[numb];
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Введите границы генерирования чисел последовательности от ";
    cin >> f1;
    cout << "До ";
    cin >> f2;
    cout << "Элементы исходной последовательности:" << endl;
    _asm {
        xor ecx, ecx
        xor edi, edi // смещение относительно начала массива
        xor ebx, ebx
        xor edi, edi
        mov ecx, numb
        mov f, ecx
        mov edi, num
        mov ebx, num2

        cycle1 :
        xor eax, eax
            xor edx, edx
    }
    x = rand() % (f2 - f1 + 1) + f1;
    cout << x << " ";
    _asm {
        xor eax, eax
        xor esi, esi
        mov edx, z
        mov eax, x
        cmp edx, 0
        je insert
        find1 :
        cmp eax, [edi][esi]
            je ravno
            add esi, 4
            cmp esi, edx
            je insert
            jmp find1

            ravno :
        inc[ebx][esi]
            jmp end1

            insert :
        mov[edi][edx], eax
            mov eax, 1
            mov[ebx][edx], eax
            add edx, 4
            inc k

            end1 :
        dec f
            cmp f, 0
            mov z, edx
            mov eax, [ebx][0]
            mov a, eax
            mov edx, [edi][0]
            mov b, edx
            jne cycle1
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Если под "упорядоченностью" имеется ввиду строго "по возрастанию" или "убыванию", то сравниваем в цикле предыдущий элемент с текущим и запоминаем "больше-меньше", если при очередной проверки этот признак меняется - не упорядоченная. если дошли до конца массива и признак не менялся - упорядоченная. Равные соседние элементы видимо игнорировать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то я не понял что делает ваш код и впервые вижу [edi][esi], и зачем два массива? Написал свою реализацию.
Мой извращенный разум хотел использовать самомодифицирующийся код, но для этого бы пришлось менять флаги кодовой секции или вызывать VirtualProtect, поэтому просто обошелся динамическим переходом.

```
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    cout << "Размер массива: ";
    int n;
    bool res = false; //результат
    cin >> n;
    int* arr = new int[n];
    cout << "Массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }
    //ebx - первый элемент массива
    //edi - индекс
    //eax - текущий элемент
    //esi - предыдущий элемент
    //ecx - направление
    __asm
    {
    mov ebx, arr
    xor edi, edi
    mov ecx, setdir
    mov eax, [ebx]              //eax = arr[0]

loop1:
    mov esi, eax                //esi = arr[i]

    inc edi                     //i++
    cmp edi, n
    je yes                      //ответ да

    lea eax, [ebx + edi * 4]
    mov eax, [eax]              //eax = arr[i]

    cmp eax, esi
    je loop1
    jmp ecx

setdir:                         //ТРЮК С ДИНАМИЧЕСКИМ ПЕРЕХОДОМ!!! ВАУ!!! 
    mov ecx, asc                //ecx = сравнение на возрастание
    jg loop1        
    mov ecx, desc               //ecx = сравнение на убывание
    jmp loop1
asc:
    jge loop1                   //если esi > eax, то ответ нет
    jmp exit1
desc:
    jle loop1                   //если esi < eax, то ответ нет
    jmp exit1
yes:
    inc res                     //res = true
exit1:
}
if (res) cout << "Массив упорядочен";
else cout << "Массив неупорядочен";
return 0;
}
```